# Is it correct to get a scoped service from singleton using IHttpContextAccessor?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, singleton, httpcontext

What are the possible implications or side effects of this "request-scoped service provider" implementation and usage?

```
public interface IScopedServiceProvider : IServiceProvider
{

}

public class ScopedServiceProvider : IScopedServiceProvider
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public ScopedServiceProvider(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        return _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(serviceType);
    }
}
```

The objective is basically to access a scoped service **from a given singleton service**:

Registered in the container like this:

```
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
services.AddScoped<IScopedServiceProvider, ScopedServiceProvider>();
services.AddScoped<IMyScopedService, MyScopedService>();
services.AddSingleton<IMySingletonService, MySingletonService>();
```

Used like this:

```
public class MySingletonService : IMySingletonService
{
    private readonly IScopedServiceProvider _scopedServiceProvider;

    public MySingletonService(IScopedServiceProvider scopedServiceProvider)
    {
        _scopedServiceProvider = scopedServiceProvider;
    }

    public void DoWork()
    {
        var scopedService = _scopedServiceProvider.GetService<IMyScopedService>();
        scopedService.DoAnotherWork();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just inject `IServiceProvider` or use `IServiceScopeFactory`?

Comment: Because the service provider must be from the same scope to get the right instance (one per request). The factory would create another scope, but how would I get it anywhere along the request?

Comment: In other words, if you inject the IServiceProvider, any call to GetService will always return the IMyScopedService created at the first request.

Comment: What else have you tried?  What problems does the current implementation cause?

Comment: Actually I'm not sure if it is a correct approach, e.g. if it is thread-safe or if there are another obvious alternative. Changing the singleton to scoped would be a good alternative in most cases, but not in my case, because that class should not be instantiated on each request.

Comment: Is the singleton being used for background tasks?  If so, perhaps have a look at [background tasks with hosted services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-2.1).

Comment: No.. It is called per request and is just too expensive to be created every time. I've reached that link a few hours ago, it's very interesting for other scenarios!

Comment: Shouldn't you be able to inject `IHttpContextAccessor` and request services from that at runtime? Making the wrapper around it scoped is pretty pointless since the accessor is singleton anyway.

Comment: @juunas the point is that the wrapper hides the HttpContextAcessor. The client of IScopedServiceProvider doesn't need to know (i.e reference) any of AspNet Http stuff. It just need to be aware of Microsoft dependency Injection.

Comment: Alright, but then the wrapper can also be singleton. Since its dependency is singleton anyway, it gets the same instance of the accessor in every scope.